# Modernizr tests not working on custom build

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, modernizr

## The Issue

I am currently experiencing a very odd issue with Modernizr... I have compiled my own build of modernizr into `/node_modules/modernizr/modernizr.js`, which I load into my app like so (compiled with webpack):

```
window.Modernizr = require('modernizr/modernizr.js');

if (!Modernizr.flexbox || !Modernizr.srcset) {
    console.log("A'rite, you seem to be living in the dark ages...");
}
```

For some reason, Modernizr is returning `undefined` on both of these tests, and is therefore failing. However, before you say I have compiled my build incorrectly, it **is** adding the classes correctly to `<htmll>` so I can confirm the javascript file is running correctly (to a certain extent)

What on earth is going on? Am I missing something really obvious?

I had this working on another site I built a few months ago so I have looked at the code there and the only difference is that I have the 'modernizr-loader' dependency in package.json and I am using `import Modernizr...` instead, but as far as I can see, I am not even using the modernizr-loaded...

## I have tried...

I thought it might be to do with running it before the DOM was ready so I ran the following and they all failed:

```
// All of the following failed!

setTimeout(function() {
    if (!Modernizr.flexbox || !Modernizr.srcset) {
        console.log("A'rite, you seem to be living in the dark ages...");
    }
}, 5000);

$('document').ready(function() {
    // The same...
});
```

Just to prove it wasn't anything to do with the DOM, I also tried the following **before** running the tests:

```
console.log($('html').attr('class'));
```

This returned:

```
js flexbox flexboxlegacy no-flexboxtweener flexwrap srcset
```

## Update

To add a little mix to the issue, the following works:

```
// Changed to 'import' from 'require'
import Modernizr from 'modernizr/modernizr.js';

// Notice the 'window.'
console.log(window.Modernizr);
```

What on earth is going on... The above works for some reason, but the other methods do not. I must be missing something

Comment: Modernizr doesn't check the classes for compliance; it's what adds the classes to the `html` element. The code which tests is at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/flexbox.js; I'll leave it to you to trace those function calls...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Yes, I already figured this out, the relevance of the HTML classes is that it confirms that it has successfully loaded my custom build of Modernizr. What I cannot figure out is why the tests are not working despite me importing the correct build...

Comment: So, the problem is that the properties are not getting set? I'd remove the stuff about the classes from the title and most of the content except the tail end to say you're using them to confirm the actions of Modernizr. You'll also want to show the code of your altered build; it may be you're doing something wrong there.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I have just found something that makes it even more confusing... See my update, I will remove the bits you suggested :-)

Comment: When you say `window.Modernizr` is working, you mean the tests?

Comment: @ChinLeung yes, the tests are working when I use it in that way... I have absolutely no idea why that is...

Comment: @ChinLeung what’s weird is that it appears there are two instances of Modernizr. If I run ‘Modernizr.flexbox’ it returns ‘undefined’, but if I run ‘window.Modernizr.flexbox’, it works, but only when using ‘import’, not ‘require’. If I run ‘console.log(Modernizr)’, it returns an object, not ‘undefined’... so wierd!

Comment: I think it's because when you import `Modernizr`, it creates a variable named `Modernizr`, hence the object you see in the console. But Modernizr saves the tests result in the `window.Moderznir` variable. What if you try `import SomethingElse from 'modernizr/modernizr.js';` ?

Comment: @ChinLeung I think you may be right, I have changed the script to literally just be `require('modernizr/modernizr.js');` instead of `window.Modernizr = require('modernizr/modernizr.js');`. This has fixed the issue so I can now call `Modernizr.flexbox' without `window` and it works. It is confusing because the other site I build several months ago did not have this issue - I guess it i just a different version of Modernizr...

Comment: Good to know! :)